# Does onsubmit executes before submitting data to database?

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, onsubmit

The problem is I intend to execute a particular javascript before submitting the form.
I know the onsubmit event handler can be used for checking or validating form.
I need to check for a hidden row in the table which if exists i intend to delete it as it will have value '' instead of an integer.
But this does not work. here is the code

```
<form name = "add_courses" action = "degree_to_college.jsp" method = "POST" onsubmit = "checkHidden()">
......
<button class =" btn btn-primary large" type = "submit" >MODIFY</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
.....
</form>
```

Here is the javascript.

```
 function checkHidden(){
      if(document.getElementById("select_degree").style.display == "none"){
          document.getElementById("add_degree").deleteRow(-1);   
      }


   }
```

The error i get on submitting the form which shows that the row with empty value is not deleted.
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'rating' at row 1

Is the data parsed before the onsubmit event, if yes then is there an alternate or am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to return a boolean value from `checkHidden()`. only when the true is returned, it submits the form